# Cisco AP commands dissapeared after IOS downgrade

Tags: cisco, ios, wlan

`enter code here`After downgrading a Cisco 881w AP (WLAN-AP), something went weird.

When I connect on the WLAN-AP interface using:

```
service-module wlan-ap0 session
```

I got this prompt:

```
AP588d.09ba.156e>
```

Then when I input "enable", it asks me for a password, which have been resetted for an unknown reason and is now "Cisco". Then I got this prompt:

```
AP588d.09ba.156e#
```

The weird thing is that all the configuration has been resetted (so the wifi does not work anymore), and when I type "?", only these commands are available to me:

```
Exec commands:
  cd               Change current directory
  clear            Reset functions
  clock            Manage the system clock
  crypto           Encryption related commands.
  debug            Debugging functions (see also 'undebug')
  delete           Delete a file
  dir              List files on a filesystem
  disable          Turn off privileged commands
  enable           Turn on privileged commands
  exit             Exit from the EXEC
  fsck             Fsck a filesystem
  help             Description of the interactive help system
  led              LED functions
  lock             Lock the terminal
  login            Log in as a particular user
  logout           Exit from the EXEC
  lwapp            lwapp exec commands
  mkdir            Create new directory
  monitor          Monitoring different system events
  more             Display the contents of a file
  name-connection  Name an existing network connection
  no               Disable debugging functions
  ping             Send echo messages
  pwd              Display current working directory
  release          Release a resource
  reload           Halt and perform a cold restart
  rename           Rename a file
  renew            Renew a resource
  rmdir            Remove existing directory
  save             Start to save raise_interrupt_level stack
  send             Send a message to other tty lines
  set              Set system parameter (not config)
  show             Show running system information
  systat           Display information about terminal lines
  terminal         Set terminal line parameters
  test             Test subsystems, memory, and interfaces
  traceroute       Trace route to destination
  undebug          Disable debugging functions (see also 'debug')
  upgrade          Upgrade software
  verify           Verify a file
  where            List active connections
```

So there I no "copy" or "conf t" command, and no "archive" command to push a new IOS into it.

Additionnally, I have privileges level 15:

```
AP588d.09ba.156e#show privilege
Current privilege level is 15
```

Please help me to recover a working IOS on the AP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to elevate to a higher privilege level. It seems to me like the reset shut off your authorization command, so you're logging in at priv 1. Just run `enable` and use the password. You should get the ability to use config t after that, and your service module command. Worse case, you might have to make some changes in config mode to the interface you use to access the service module. Good luck! (If you want the authorization tripped at login again, go into config mode and issue the following two commands:
`aaa authorization exec default local`
`aaa authorization console`
I hope that helps!)

Comment: I have priviledge level 15.